# How To Remove The Double Quotes From The Json data Result..?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, web-services, cordova

I developing a windows phone 7 application using Phonegap. now I currently Working With The Web service Data Binding.

My Web service return Json Format like Below:

```
LocationAddress: "85 Cowley Avenue, Hyderabad",
```

My Ajax Call

```
$.ajax({

            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
            crossDomain: true,
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function (data) {
                $('.locaddress').append(JSON.stringify(data[0].LocationAddress));
});
```

MY html code

```
<tr>
<td class="heading">locationaddress</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="locaddress"> </td>
</tr>
```

My Output come Like This :

```
"85 Cowley Avenue, Hyderabad"
```

I Want To remove The Double Quotes

I Need Solution For This ...

I Try The Following Method It's Not Work

```
var test = "\"House\"";
console.log(test);
console.log(test.replace(/\"/g, ""));
```

Thank You....

Comment: `$('.locaddress').append(data[0].LocationAddress);` ???

Comment: Just avoid JSON.stringify and try again

Comment: Thank You Wolff,Bizzon Now It's Working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this

```
   $('.locaddress').append(data[0].LocationAddress);
```